# Webservice returning 403 error

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx, http-status-code-403

I'm wondering whether I'm receiving the 403 errors because there are too many attempted connections being made to the webservice. If this is the case how do I get around it? I've tried creating a new instance of `InternalWebService` each time and disposing of the old one but I get the same problem. I've disabled the firewall and the webservice is located locally at the moment. I beginning to think it may be a problem with the credentials but the control tree is populated via the webservice at some stage. If I browse to the webmethods in my browser I can run them all.

I return an instance of the webservice from my login handler `loginsession.cs`:

```
static LoginSession()
{
    ...
    g_NavigatorWebService = new InternalWebService();
    g_NavigatorWebService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    ...
}       

public static InternalWebService NavigatorWebService
{
    get
    {
        return g_NavigatorWebService;
    }
}
```

I have a tree view control which uses the webservice to populate itself. `IncidentTreeViewControl.cs`:

```
public IncidentTreeView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    m_WebService    = LoginSession.NavigatorWebService;
    ...
}
public void Populate()
{
    m_WebService.BeginGetIncidentSummaryByCompany(new AsyncCallback(IncidentSummaryByClientComplete), null);
    m_WebService.BeginGetIncidentSummaryByDepartment(new AsyncCallback(IncidentSummaryByDepartmentComplete), null);
    ...
}
private void IncidentSummaryByClientComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    MyTypedDataSet data = m_WebService.EndGetIncidentSummaryByCompany(ar); //403
    ..cont...
}
```

I'm getting the 403 on the last line.

Comment: Does it 403 on the first request, or after a few requests, or after a few days?

Comment: This was also the first question I had. This is a VERY important piece of information. Is it 100% of time? Just after the first request? Or randomly?

Comment: What version is your web server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the sub-code of 403 ? Only 403-9 and 403-15 seem to be related to too much traffic, which is itself related to your licence, so there is nothing that can be done about this, except buy new licences or reduce the amount of requests.

But other sub-codes of 403 are more related to authorization, which may be a more likely reason for your problem.